# prove logarithmic inequality for N>1200

Tags: logarithms

For N > 1200 how can i prove that

3.09N/Log(N) + 1 <= 1.7(2N+1)/Log(2N+1)

(sorry, could not figure out how to put the 'less than or equal' symbol there, tried \leq)

Comment: \leq is correct.  You need to enclose $\LaTeX$ in dollar signs, so $\leq$ is the result. Similarly, \log will give it in the proper font:  $\log$.  You might see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get started.

Comment: It is very close.  I would evaluate it at $N=1200$ first and find it satisfied.  Then write it as wanting to prove $\frac {3.09N+1}{3.4N+1.7}-\frac {\log N}{\log (2N+1)}\leq 0$, take the derivative of the left, and show it is negative.  It looks so from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+derivative+of++%283.09x%2B1%29%2F%283.4+x+%2B+1.7%29-log%28x%29%2Flog%282x%2B1%29++from+1200+to+2000) but I didn't look really hard, which is why this is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just by derivation: let 
$$f(x):=1.7\frac{2x+1}{\log (2x+1)} - 3.09\frac{x}{\log x}-1,$$
$$f'(x)= 3.4 \frac{\log(2x+1)-1}{\log^2(2x+1)} - 3.09 \frac{\log x-1}{\log^2x}. $$

1. need to check $f'(x)>0$ for $x>1200$, hence
   $$3.4 \frac{\log(2x+1)-1}{\log^2(2x+1)} - 3.09 \frac{\log x-1}{\log^2x} \geq 0$$
   $$\frac{3.4}{3.09}\geq  \frac{\log x-1}{\log^2x} \frac{\log^2(2x+1)}{\log(2x+1)-1} \geq \frac{\log x-1}{\log^2x}  \frac{\log^2(2x+1)}{\log(2x+1)}=\frac{\log x-1}{\log^2x}\log (2x)$$
   $$ = \frac{\log 2+\log x}{\log x}-\frac{\log (2x)}{\log^2x}= 1+\frac{\log 2}{\log x}-\frac{\log (2x)}{\log^2x}.$$
   Since $x\mapsto \frac{\log 2}{\log x}$ is decreasing, we get $\frac{\log 2}{\log x} \leq \frac{\log2}{\log1200} \approx 0.097763$. Since $\frac{3.4}{3.09}>1+0.097763$, we have $f'(x)>0$ for $x\geq 1200$.
2. since $f(1200)=1.7\frac{2401}{\log 2401} - 3.09\frac{1200}{\log 1200}-1>0$, your inequality follows.